# Белый фон для полупрозрачных изображений

Tags: php

Парсю картинки. Картинки приходят разного размера по ширине, высоте, есть обрезанные по контуру изображения, есть на белом фоне. Эти картинки при парсинге надо наложить на заготовленный фон (квадрат), предварительно высчитав по ширине или высоте растянуть и замостить по центру заготовленного фона. Для тестирования, чтоб рамки фона были видны и контролировать правильность расположения на нём картинки, у него стоит не белый, а розовый фон.

Накрапал небольшой класс, всё работает.

```
class ImageHelper
{
    const BG_SIZE = 700;
    const IMG_SIZE = 700;

    public $image_type;
    public $image;
    public $bg_img;
    public $final_img;

    public static function correctImage($path)
    {
        $coefficient = 1.15;
        $size_limit = 1000;
        $data = getimagesize($path);
        $width = (int) @$data[0];
        $height = (int) @$data[1];
        if($width < $size_limit && $height < $size_limit){
            return true; 
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function createBg(){
        $im  = imagecreatetruecolor(self::BG_SIZE, self::BG_SIZE);
        $bgc = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 155, 255);
        imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bgc);
        $this->bg_img = $im;
    }

    public function load($filename) {
        $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
        $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
        if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
           $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
           $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
        } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
           $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
        } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_WEBP ) {
           $this->image = imagecreatefromwebp($filename);
        }
    }

    public function getWidth() {
        return imagesx($this->image);
    }

    public function getHeight() {
        return imagesy($this->image);
    }

    public function resize($width,$height) {
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
        $this->image = $new_image;
    }

    public function newSize($filename){
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
        $new_size = [];

        if ($width > $height){
            $new_size['width'] = self::IMG_SIZE;
            $new_size['height'] = self::IMG_SIZE * $height / $width;
            $new_size['top'] = (self::BG_SIZE - (self::IMG_SIZE * $height / $width)) / 2;
            $new_size['left'] = 0;
        } elseif ($width == $height) {
            $new_size['width'] = self::IMG_SIZE;
            $new_size['height'] = self::IMG_SIZE;
            $new_size['top'] = 0;
            $new_size['left'] = 0;
        } else {
            $new_size['width'] = self::IMG_SIZE * $width / $height;
            $new_size['height'] = self::IMG_SIZE;
            $new_size['top'] = 0;
            $new_size['left'] = (self::BG_SIZE - (self::IMG_SIZE * $width / $height)) / 2;
        }
        return $new_size;
    }

    public function merge($filename) {
        $this->createBg();
        $this->load($filename);
        $new_size = $this->newSize($filename);
        $this->resize($new_size['width'],$new_size['height']);
        imagecopymerge($this->bg_img, $this->image, $new_size['left'], $new_size['top'], 0, 0, $new_size['width'], $new_size['height'], 100);
        imagewebp($this->bg_img,'final.webp',80);
    }

}
```

Вызываю так:

```
//$filename = 'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/w.05318.png';    //1096 x 3576
//$filename = 'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/67012146.jpg';   //2560 x 4000
//$filename = 'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/w.02690.png';    //640 x 480
//$filename = 'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/BM.2402.png';    //700 x 436       //!!!!!!!!!!
//$filename = 'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/65413889.png';   //250 x 250   
//$filename = 'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/10700300.png';   //1500 x 1500     //!!!!!!
$filename = 'http://cdn.io-opt.com/images/products/t.90102.png';    //885 x 1500      //!!!!!

$ih = new ImageHelper();
$ih->merge($filename);
echo Html::img('final.webp');
die();
```

Всё бы хорошо, но если заходит картинка, которая обрезана по контуру (без своего личного фона), то накладываясь на мой заготовленный фон, вокруг неё откуда-то берётся чёрная рамка, которую я не могу побороть. Выглядит она вот так http://joxi.ru/eAOQd73Spkw41m Как я понимаю суть проблемы: у обрезанной по контуру картинки, скорее всего нет начального пиксела с координатами 0, 0 и оно, скорее всего из-за его отсутствия, не зная какой цвет сделать, лепит этот чёрный цвет. Однако я не смог подтвердить своё предположение, а другого нет. Прошу помощи :)

Comment: возможно вам в помощь функции `imagesavealpha()` и `imagealphablending()`

Comment: Добавил в метод load()                   
  `imagealphablending($this->image, false);
  imagesavealpha($this->image, true);
  imagepng($this->image,'test.png');`
Для проверки вставил `imagepng($this->image,'test.png')` Теперь в test.png картинка получается без какого-то ни было фона, просто обрезанная по изображению, полупрозрачная. В принципе это не плохо, что она такая идёт в метод merge(). И походу это именно функция imagecopymerge фигачит этот фон. У неё есть последний параметр pct, им можно было бы убрать чёрный фон, но он устанавливает полупрозрачность и для самого изображения.

Comment: я вообще это применил бы не к исходной картинке, а создаваемой ) вы лучше создайте [mcve] а не этот класс, быстрее подскажут. как то многовато там текста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

всё, разобрался. На этапе ресайза у меня была функция imagecreatetruecolor(), а согласно спецификации она возвращает "идентификатор изображения, представляющий **черное** изображение заданного размера." добавил изменение фона на нужный цвет. В такой редакции всё работает:

```
public function resize($width,$height) {
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);    // вот эта строка добавляла чёрную область
    //добавлено
    $bgc = imagecolorallocate($new_image, 255, 255, 255);  
    imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $bgc);
    ////добавлено
    imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
    $this->image = $new_image;
}
```

Comment: Вы случайно поставили метку "общий". Данная метка предполагает "коллективное" написание вопроса, т.е. что бы со временем накопить все знания по-вопросу несколькими учасниками сайта. В даном случае галочка "общий" не нужна.

Comment: Понял, спасибо) ещё бы подскажите как сделать воспроизводимый пример

Comment: воспроизводимый пример означает что если я с вопроса на сайте сделаю copy а у себя в программе (например Notepad++) сделаю paste - то у меня заработает так же само как и у вас. Как это сделать... иногда просто скопирова всё, а иногда нужно поработать с кодом... хорошего рецепта нету.